# Is this relation P an equivalence relation or a partial order relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, relations

I am having trouble with partial order and equivalence relations. I was wondering if someone can guide me through this problem.

Let $Σ$ be the set of letters {$a, b, . . . z$}.

Let $Σ^∗$ be the set of all finite string made of the letters $Σ$, for example
“cat” $∈$ $Σ^∗$, “dog” $∈ Σ^∗$, “mathematics” $∈ Σ^∗$, “” $∈ Σ^∗$ (the empty string).
We define a permutation relation $P$:

$P =$ {$(x, y)$ $∈ Σ^∗ × Σ^∗$| $x$ is a permutation of $y$}.
It contains all the pairs of strings that are permutations of each other, for example

(“flow”, “wolf”) $∈ P$, (“teenager”, “generate”) $∈ P$, (“player”, “replay”) $∈ P$.

Is this relation P an equivalence relation or a partial order relation? Explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflectivity: Every word is a permutation of itself, so $P$ is reflective.

Symmetric: If $x$ is a permutation of $y$, then clearly $y$ is a permutation of $x$, so $P$ is symmetric.

Transitivity: If $y$ is a permutation of $x$ and $z$ a permutation of $y$ then $z$ is a permutation of $x$ (because all three have the same letters), hence $P$ is transitive.

Therefore $P$ is an equivalence relation.

To see whether it is a partial order we must check if $P$ is antisymmetric. Take $x\neq y$ such that $x$ is a permutation of $y$. By symmetry, $y$ is a permutation of $x$ but $x\neq y$. $P$ is therefore not antisymmetric and therefore not a partial order.